# Is it possible to define a custom exceptions_app for rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

In `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions` of rails, it allows me to redefine how exceptions are handled and displayed in the entire application. But is the same / something similar available for a rails engine?